# How to get html of a SAP UI5 control

Tags: sapui5

Normally when using SAP UI5, we use the following code

```
this.appContent.placeAt('content');
```

This will render the content  element.

But I just want the html of appContent UI5 control without rendering it. How to do that?

The reason I want to do it is because I want to use sap.ui.template to build a carousel and I want to add get raw HTML of UI5 control and add it as a string to a template instead of rendering it directly.

Comment: Are you trying to get an HTML element of the control without rendering it beforehand or after rendering?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to get HTML element without rendering

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this.appContent` is a control, then after the contol has been rendered just call

```
var $domRef = this.appContent.$():
```

or [getDomRef()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/getDomRef) (visibility is protected!)

```
var domRef = this.appContent.getDomRef():
```

Be aware when to call this **after** the control has been rendered, i.e. like this:

```
this.appContent.addEventDelegate({

    onAfterRendering : function(oEvent){
        var $domRef = oEvent.srcControl.$();
        // now do something
    }
});
this.appContent.placeAt('content');
```

However, I would try to avoid using placeAt.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, is it possible to get HTML without rendering? I do not want to have a HTML DOM element.

Comment: No, at least not without ugly tricks. Keep in mind the html can change over time, so you would have to think about getting the latest html if needed. What is your exact use case? Would you mind updating your question by adding all details needed to answer the question?

Comment: Thank you again, I edited the question, please let me know if anything is not clearly.